# Write a spec to assert that a certain record has been deleted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Counting the number of instances is one way to find out if *something* has been deleted:

```
it "should delete the mutual_friendship" do
    @friendship_1.delete_mutual_friendship!
    UserFriendship.count.should == 0
end
```

However, is it possible to test that a certain record has been deleted? In my case, @friendship_1? Can I test that @friendship_1's attributes no longer exist in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `destroyed?`:

```
it "should delete the mutual_friendship" do
  @friendship_1.delete_mutual_friendship!
  @friendship_1.should be_destroyed
  # @friendship_2.should be_destroyed
end
```

Documentation: [`destroyed`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-destroyed-3F)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could `reload` the record and test that it will raise an error:

```
it "should delete the mutual_friendship" do
    @friendship_1.delete_mutual_friendship!
    @friendship_1.reload.should raise_error
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The [ActiveRecord#exists? method](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#existence-of-objects) lets you test for the existence of a record in the database. You can test for any conditions you want, but assuming testing for the id is sufficient, you can use:

```
it "should delete the mutual_friendship" do
  @friendship_1.delete_mutual_friendship!
  expect(UserFriendship.exists?(@friendship.id)).to be_false
end
```

As an aside, all the documentation I've found for this method indicates it returns `true` or `false`, but it really should say `truthy` or 'falsy`, per this [commit](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/aec0e68) which, for reasons I can't figure out, isn't reflected in the master branch.